# unity android app crash issue

Tags: android, unity-game-engine

On my device app perfect work , no crash but play store crash log showing crash issue and crash issue like as below.

app in unity 2017.2 version

crash log

```
LGE LG K10 LTE (m253), 1536MB RAM, Android 6.0
Report 1

java.lang.RuntimeException: 
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2434)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2494)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900 (ActivityThread.java:157)
  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage (ActivityThread.java:1356)
  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage (Handler.java:102)
  at android.os.Looper.loop (Looper.java:148)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.main (ActivityThread.java:5530)
  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke (Native Method)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run (ZygoteInit.java:733)
  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:623)
Caused by: android.app.Fragment$InstantiationException: 
  at android.app.Fragment.instantiate (Fragment.java:628)
  at android.app.FragmentState.instantiate (Fragment.java:106)
  at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.restoreAllState (FragmentManager.java:1858)
  at android.app.FragmentController.restoreAllState (FragmentController.java:122)
  at android.app.Activity.onCreate (Activity.java:919)
  at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity.onCreate (Unknown Source)
  at com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerNativeActivity.onCreate (Unknown Source)
  at android.app.Activity.performCreate (Activity.java:6272)
  at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate (Instrumentation.java:1108)
  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity (ActivityThread.java:2387)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalAccessException: 
  at java.lang.Class.newInstance (Native Method)
  at android.app.Fragment.instantiate (Fragment.java:613)
```

Comment: There is not enough information to help you in any case.  You'll have to provide the code that belongs to that crash. It looks like the app is crashing during startup. So it would be intresting what your app.xaml.cs does in the Start method, aswell as what your Android Activity does during startup

Answer (score 0):

It's a known Unity bug, and as stated [here](https://forum.unity.com/threads/crash-reports-caused-by-android-app-fragment-instantiationexception.472522/), it was fixed in the following Unity versions: **2017.3.0b8**, **2017.2.0p2**, **2017.1.2p3**, **5.6.4p3**.